# Nodejs - keepAlive indication that same connection is used

Tags: node.js, keep-alive

I've recently implemented a keepAlive in my nodejs application like so:

```
var keepAliveOptions = {
  keepAlive: true,
  maxSockets: 1,
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000
};
```

and then passing 'keepAliveOptions' under 'agentOptions' in the request.
In the response I'm able to see 'keepAlive: true'.

But is there a way to check how many times the connection was used? or if it was changed?

In addition, is there a recommended number of sockets to use for keep-alive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `request.connection` object, which is a `<net.socket>`, will be the same for each request which reuses a socket. You could add a listener to the `connect` event of this socket object to count how many times each socket is used.

Here is a basic example, relevant if you are using the http module in your application:

```
server.on("connection", function(connection) {
  connection.number_of_times_used = 0;
});

server.on("request", function(request) {
  request.connection.number_of_times_used++;
  console.log("Request used " + request.connection.number_of_times_used + " times")
});
```

To answer your last question: There is no recommended number of sockets to use for this, as each application will have different requirements and different numbers of users. In your case, I would stick with 1 until you notice any performance issues, and then you can adjust the maxSockets value accordingly.

Comment: @david-faiz Please post a code example if you would like a code snippet showing you how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is the recommended number of sockets to use for keep-alive? if there is one.

Comment: @DavidFaiz I have updated my answer. If you think I have answered your question please consider accepting my answer as the correct one.

Comment: @DavidFaiz Did I answer your question? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.